# Method not visible in public view asp.net MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello I'm starting with asp.net MVC 4 for

And I have a doubt, you can not access by razor a simple method that returns a string in my controller?

Example I have a list of client and every time it loads a record I want to call my method.

look

My method created in `ClientController`

```
public string returnValue()
{
    return "RetornaTest";
}
```

Here's where I should call this method

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
          **right here**
        </td>
        <td>
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NomeCliente)
        </td>
```

I tried to call directly `@this.returnValue()`

however the method is not visible.

how to Solve

Comment: view server-side script is not executed in the context of a controller

Comment: `Html.Action` and `Html.RenderAction` are created to such scenarios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly type my view to a view model and set up a read-only property in the view model which would then be accessible in the same way as all other properties are in my view. You could then add your method logic to your read-only property.

Comment: Given the `DisplayFor` there is already a model being passed to the `View`. It sounds like the OP really needs to read up on Separation of Concern and how that applies to the MVC pattern as a whole.

Comment: Good point on the DisplayFor, agreed also on the higher level investigation being a good idea.